# How to remove "www." from $ssl_server_name

Tags: nginx

I'm writing an nginx configuration that will serve on few hundred domains.
To enable SSL, I've issued letsenctrypt certificates for all of them, and used this config:

```
http {
  map $ssl_server_name $cert_folder {
    default   $ssl_server_name;
  }
  server {
    listen          <ip>:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name     _;
    ssl_certificate          /etc/letsencrypt/live/$cert_folder/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key      /etc/letsencrypt/live/$cert_folder/privkey.pem;
        
    [...]
  }
}
```

But it doesn't find certificate files when someone uses address like "www.example.com", since there is no such folder.

Certificates are issued for both versions, so I'd like to just remove "www." from $cert_folder variable if it's there.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could try adding this to your map: `~*^www\.(?<short_name>.*)$ $short_name;`

Comment: Using variables in `ssl_certificate` directive has serious performance implications. It is best to write a script to extract all the common names from the certificate file, append www. versions to the list, and use that for `server_name` directive instead of "catch-all" underscore approach.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: As a simpler solution to this, without extra processing, generate LetsEncrypt certificate using either FQDN with any subdomain(s) combination (as in 'www' or else) then at certificate issuance, preferably from a shell script, `symlink` subdomains folders to appropriate containing folder - i *stricty AVOID* referencing `/etc/letsencrypt` folder in my configs and rather create, again at issue time and using a custom shell script, a `/etc/nginx/ssl/FQDN` dir that contains a generated DH file and symlinks to letsencrypt/live/FQDN fullchain and privkey files. Wildcard cers are a solution, too.

Comment: Precedent works if you use more than one FQDN - i.e: if you are not building a `username.subdomain.FQDN` saga where minute registered users get new subdomains. There are many contexts but with the usual scenario of only a few subdomains per FQDN, i have instances supplying many hundred domains, without issues (configs are fairly standard so shell script is responsible for generating, from custom templates, configs/ssl/special/anything when adding new domains..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can best achieve this using map but you need to filter the domain using Perl regex as follows:

```
map $ssl_server_name $cert_folder {
      default $ssl_server_name;
      ~*www.(.*) $1;
 }
```

Your variable **$cert_folder** will now be the value of www.**(domain_name)**

**ie** *it will be example.com in the place of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*

I have tested this and it works.